# Customizing Eclipse application launcher when launching a plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

We are writing an Eclipse plugin that will work in a ClearCase environment i.e., our plugin will work along with the ClearCase SCM plugin for eclipse(available from IBM).

When developing the plugin, our eclipse(RCP & RAP) don't need ClearCase plugin. However, when we launch the plugin thru "[Eclipse Application Launcher](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/intro/pde_overview.htm)", the new eclipse does need the ClearCase plugin.

Is it possible to configure the "Eclipse Application Launcher" to include ClearCase plugin(or any different plugin that's not in the base eclipse) when it fires up another eclipse instance?

I could not find a way to do this from the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Target platform](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/concepts/target.htm) is what you are looking for.

You can use a pure Eclipse release(such as Juno) as development tool, then use another collection of compile and runtime plug-ins via specifying a target platform.